# select distinct first row from database

Tags: postgresql, distinct

```
number      | time
```

421112233444 | 1304010250 
 421112233444 | 1304272979 
 421001122333 | 1303563263 
 421112233444 | 1300217115 
 421001122333 | 1303649310

i need to return unique first row with lowest number from second row, like this:

421112233444 | 1300217115 
421001122333 | 1303563263

any idea?

i try SELECT ph.number, mo.time from (select distinct(number) from table) ph, table mo where mo.number = ph.number;

but it returns both uniques:

421112233444 | 1304010250 
 421112233444 | 1304272979 
 421001122333 | 1303563263 
 421112233444 | 1300217115 
 421001122333 | 1303649310

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ON will help :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/sql-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GROUP BY to do this:

```
SELECT number, MIN(time)
FROM table
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY number DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: oh, that really helped me right now! but why just `ORDER BY` command not work here? I got almost same stuff in query, but if I leave just `ORDER BY` i get this `column “p.mydate” must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: You get that message because you have an unaggregated column in your select clause that's also not in your group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ph.number, min(mo.time) from (select distinct(number) from table) ph, table mo group by ph.number
```